# Adding a story board in Nav Controller

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder

I have a `ViewController` which is inside `NavigationController`, lets call this VC `ABCViewController`. Now i have created a story board which is not inside the `NavigationController`. Now i want to push the `storyboard` inside the `NavigationController` when some button is pressed on the `ABCViewController`.

any Help.

Comment: How can you push storyboard in a navigation controller, I think navigation controller itself stays in a storyboard?

Comment: Add a UIStoryBoard, then drag UINavigationController inside this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First load your storyboard:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myVC"];
```

Then Push the wanted UIViewController to your `UINavigationController`

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]
```